# Passing and receiving multiple props to a mapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm mapping the `TeamsContainer` component and trying to pass it multiple props. However what i've tried doesn't seem to be working. This is the page where the component is called:

```
const UserPage: NextPage<Props> = ({ tournaments, trainerData }) => {
  const [leagueFilter, setLeagueFilter] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
        <Select onChange={(e) => setLeagueFilter(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="Great">Great</option>
          <option value="Ultra">Ultra</option>
          <option value="Master">Master</option>
        </Select>
        {tournaments.map((tournament: Tournament, index: number) => (
          <TeamsContainer
            key={tournament.bout + tournament.league}
            {...tournament}
            leagueFilter={leagueFilter}
          />
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

and here is part of the `TeamsContainer` component.

```
import { Tournament } from "../types";

interface Props {
  tournament: Tournament;
  leagueFilter: string;
}

const TeamsContainer: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ leagueFilter, ...tournament }) => {

  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
};
export default TeamsContainer;
```

if i replace `<Props>` with `<Tournament>` and remove `leagueFilter` it works, but with the code im using above i get the error `Property does not exist on type '{ tournament: Tournament; children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)`

I'm not sure how to set the `Props` interface within the mapped function, or if this is the way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing `Props` interface is fine, the problem is that you're using spread and rest unnecessarily. Your interface expects to see a property called `tournament`, not the individual properties that `Tournament` has. So pass it a `Tournament` (`tournament={tournament}` rather than `...tournament`):

```
{tournaments.map((tournament: Tournament, index: number) => (
  <TeamsContainer
    key={tournament.bout + tournament.league}
    tournament={tournament}
    leagueFilter={leagueFilter}
  />
))}
```

...and receive it without using rest syntax (`tournament` instead of `...tournament`):

```
const TeamsContainer: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ leagueFilter, tournament }) => {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Tbh, i'm not quite sure why i used the spread/rest operator. I think i had trouble passing tournament props originally, and that solved it. Anyways thanks again :)